# maven build failing to download com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6 dependency

Tags: java, docker, maven

Previously my build is running fine but all of a sudden it's failing with the below error.

```
Failed to collect dependencies at ar.com.fdvs:DynamicJasper:jar:5.3.0 -> net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.8.0 -> com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js6 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/, default, releases+snapshots), jr-ce-releases (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

These are the dependencies I am using in my code.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.js6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ar.com.fdvs/DynamicJasper-core-fonts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper-core-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I tried changing the DynamicJasper version also but no luck.

In the docker file, I am using the below image as a base image.

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using maven 3.6? mvn version in Dockerfile for test...
http blocker was introduced in maven 3.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
  <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My issue resolved after adding this dependency.

Answer (score 8):

if you run maven on linux .then use this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.12.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!--        "jasperreports" can't resolve "itext" dependency on jenkins.so it added independently-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

The modified versions of iText 2.1.7 are available on this public repository:

https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/ui/native/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext

Jars are available for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is error in downloading `com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js6`. I think there is a version number change in `maven repository`. there is not any `2.1.7.js6` version in maven repository.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

for your ref:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7

Comment: As you suggest i changed the version.Now i am getting below error.

**
Failed to collect dependencies at ar.com.fdvs:DynamicJasper:jar:5.1.0 -> net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:4.8.0 -> com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js1: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js1 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [jasperreports (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]
**

Comment: From the error log, what I see is `DynamicJasper:jar:5.1.0` is referring to `jasperreports:jar:4.8.0` and it is referring to `itext:jar:2.1.7.js1`. if you go through the mvn repository versions has been change.. you should update the version of your dependency and also the transitive dependency as well.

Comment: for example  `com.lowagie.itext` has been moved to `com.itextpdf.itextpdf`. you should visit the mvn repository and look for compiled dependencies of the library you have been using and update the version accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this dependency folder from users\.m2 folder and run maven install again. This will remove the old dependency which is causing issues and will download the same dependency again.